# Jackson JSON parsing, how to map 2 possible objects into one master object

Tags: json, jackson, resteasy

I'm using Jboss Resteasy and Jackson to marshall a response into an object. The problem is that the API I'm connecting to either returns a single object of type A if it's an error or a list of objects of type B if it is successful. My goal would be to have an object C like the following:

```
class C {
   A a;
   List<B> bList;
}
```

However, when I try this I get (in the case where it returns success)

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Failed to narrow content type [collection type; class java.util.List, contains [simple type, class com.B]] with content-type annotation (com.C): Class com.C is not assignable to com.B
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.modifyTypeByAnnotation(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:797)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.constructSettableProperty(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:1375)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.addBeanProps(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:1182)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:707)
```

I'm just not sure what kind of @Json annotations I would need (or even if this possible)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to sort it out like that. RestEasy will look at your `class C` and it won't be able to figure out if your response object contains a `class A` or a `List<B>`.

You can solve this sort of deal like this:

```
public <T> T returnEntityIfValid(ClientResponse response, Class clazz) {
    try {
        return (T) response.getEntity(clazz);
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        final A node = (A) response.getEntity(A.class);
        throw new RuntimeException("ERROR: " + node.toString());
    }
}
```

The idea is we'll be expecting a specified type, but since the `Response` object obscures it from us we have to just try and grab the entity. If the response object contains your entity `class A` it will return it with no problem. Otherwise, it will try and extract it, but throw a `JsonMappingException` (which isn't throwable from `Response.getEntity()` hence the `RuntimeException`) at which point the error will be extracted from your `class B`

This has been generified to support class extraction of any entity type.

Comment: Oh god. Please don't catch RuntimeException.  Catch the specific exception or set of exceptions that are thrown by Jackson.